# Event Report filter not working

Tags: civievent, civireport

I am trying to create an event report but I am not able to filter a specific event in the Event filter, it shows as "None found" even when there are active events present and there is no error in the browser console. Kindly help me to fix the issue.[image]

Comment: What CMS are you using? Also, have you checked the error logs, You can sometimes find useful debugging information that can help :-)

Comment: @Ember I am using Drupal 7 and I didn't find logs related to this.

Answer (score 0):

It can be a good idea to clear all CiviCRM caches. You can do that using the url https://www.yourdomain.com/civicrm/menu/rebuild.

Regarding the logs, you can turn on logging and debugging in CiviCRM (https://www.yourdomain.com/civicrm/admin/setting/debug?reset=1) and then have a look at the log available in Drupal's UI first: https://www.yourdomain.com/admin/reports/dblog